# Can a system call cause a system panic in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

Please don't consider syscalls due to calls to panic() etc., which are actually supposed to panic the system. I am more interested in general purpose system calls such as [Socket](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.18/net/compat.c#L609), read, write etc. If such syscalls do cause a panic, then is this a kernel bug? My understanding is that it should be a kernel bug. If passed with wrong arguments then system-call should just abort not panic the complete system.

Comment: In theory you are right. What's your actual problem?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, no surprise here. Panic = bug.

Comment: Well, at least it can *trigger* a kernel panic. But the actual *cause* can be different (disturbed data structures, resource exhaustion, hardware failure, programming errors, the Spanish inquisition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strangely enough, this is not 100% correct.

Yes, input to system calls by a non privileged user should not cause a panic unless there is a bug in the kernel or a hardware malfunction (such as broken RAM chips).

However, this not true for a privileged user (such as root). Consider the write(2) system call, when applied to /dev/mem by a privileged user (root being the obvious example) - there is nothing stopping you from overwriting kernel memory with it.

Unix is like that - it gives you the full length of the rope to hang yourself easily, if this is what you wish to do :-)

Comment: It's quite difficult to write a good secure interface to the kernel. The easy way is to allow root only and forget about security, and then root can crash the system.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the kernel must check the syscall parameters, user permissions, resources availability and handle issues like concurrency in order to avoid crash at all costs. The bottomline is that a simple user (even root, ideally - but as mentionned by gby this is difficult since root can have direct access to the physical address space) should *never* be able to crash the system, no matter how hard she tries.